# Box2d set ground friction to maximum - no sliding

Tags: box2d

I have a box shape on an edge shape. Now I apply impulse on the box, so that it could jump. But when it is landed on the ground, it should not move any more. So I have set restitution 0 of the box. And friction of edge shape and box shape to 1. But it slides easily on the ground. How to prevent any sliding?

Comment: Box2D is not made for speed, not accuracy. Friction and restitution do not work 100% and you should not expect them to. There will often be a tiny bit of bounce when restitutions are both zero, and a tiny bit of slide when frictions are both 1. However, it should not 'slide easily', so perhaps there is still something missing in your setup.

Comment: I have changed friction to 100, and it works as needed. But I don't know what is the max, so that I could set max and be sure that it will not slide ever, even if force is very big. Should I set float max value from numeric limits (c++)?

Comment: I think the max is intended to be 1, but like I say it is not accurate at all. If you can get the results you want by tweaking the numbers, sure, change them to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, you can prevent sliding by increasing the friction high-enough.

As to what the maximum value that you can set the friction to is, there's no documented maximum for the friction value. That said, there are some limitations to what the maximum friction value can be.

Trying `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()` as the first friction value in the `VaryingFriction` Testbed test, results in the first platform that the infinite friction cube hits, disappearing. *Oops!* Not the outcome that I'd want.

A review of the [Box2D 2.3.2 C++ source code](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D) reveals friction relevant variables like:

- The `m_friction` member variable of `b2Fixture`.
- The `m_friction` member variable of `b2Contact`.
- The `friction` member variable of `b2ContactVelocityConstraint`.

These are defined as being instances of type `float32` which in turn is of type `float` - [a single precision floating-point type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). This gives us a maximal upper bound of what the following can give us (without overflow) of:

```
std::numeric_limits<float>::max()
```

The `m_friction` member variable of `b2Contact` however is essentially the result of taking the square root of the product of the fixtures' frictions:

```
std::sqrtf(m_fixtureA->m_friction * m_fixtureB->m_friction)
```

So any given fixture's `m_friction` value needs to be below the square root of float-max in order to avoid a potential overflow in this product. I.e., we get a more realistic upper bound for what any `b2Fixture`'s friction setting can be from:

```
std::sqrtf(std::numeric_limits<float>::max())
```

That might be well enough if it weren't for what happens then with the `friction` member variable of `b2ContactVelocityConstraint`; it gets multiplied (in `b2ContactSolver::SolveVelocityConstraints()`) by another float - the `normalImpulse` of every velocity constraint point. So the square-root of float-max may still be too high to be sure to avoid any potential for overflow.

And overflow may mean what happens using infinity for friction: oops! While a body disappearing due to using too high a friction value may well be a bug, short of fixing the library's source code, I think we're kind of stuck then with the square root of the max float value as an upper bound that's still risky. Incidentally, I filed an [issue](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/issues/434) about this along with a way I found to fix it.

As a rule of thumb, I'd increase a fixture's friction till there was no more sliding, and then just leave it at that.

OTOH, there are other ways of preventing sliding (besides upping the friction) like these...

1. Change the body's type. If you set the body to static after collision with the ground, it won't move physically at all. Not until you change it back to dynamic.
2. Create a joint when the box collides with the ground to bind the box to the ground.